# How to get the most important feature names of my naivebayes-classifier?

Tags: scikit-learn, naivebayes

Context: I do have a huge text dataset(~70GB) which I want use to predict if a certain stock goes up or down(labels: 0 and 1) and I want to know the most important features using a MultinomialNB-classifier.

My idea is to use the HashingVectorizer from scikitlearn to create a document-term matrix, which I use to train a MulitnomialNB-classfier. That way I fixed the size of the term-frquency table, which prevents memory-problems. A normal CountVectorizer doesn't work since the table grows larger and larger until my ram is exhausted.

After that I can show myself the `model.feature_log_prob_`/`coef_`.

Question: Is there any way to know which hash corresponds to which `model.feature_log_prob/coef_`?

If yes: I could sort them and find out the e.g. 1000 most important hashes for each class. In a second iteration over my data set, I could log which word or which words correspond to which hash in my list of 1000 most important hashes.